# send email from listview button

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have made listview from which i am fetching email id of customer . There are button to send mail from selected column. I don't know how to do it please help me. This is my code which i am working now..

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration


Partial Class dashboard
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=SuRaj;Initial Catalog=Brandstik2; Integrated Security=True")
    Dim Comp_ID, client_name As String

    Protected Sub add_company_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles add_company.Click
        add_client.Visible = True
        headings.Text = "Add New Companies"
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
            Me.BindListView()
        End If
        add_client.Visible = False
        send_request_form.Visible = False
        headings.Text = "Dashboard"

        'Dim str1 As String = "Select * from BrandstikTesti"
        'Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand(str1, con)
        'con.Open()
        'Dim rdr1 As SqlDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader

        'While rdr1.Read
        '    Label1.Text = rdr1(0)
        '    Label2.Text = rdr1(1)
        'End While
        'con.Close()
        'rdr1.Close()
        'cmd1.Dispose()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub send_request_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles send_request.Click
        add_client.Visible = False
        send_request_form.Visible = True
        headings.Text = "Send Feedback Request"
        success.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Protected Sub submit_client_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles submit_client.Click
        Dim Comp_ID, client_name, email_id As String

        form1.Visible = True
        Comp_ID = TextBox1.Text
        client_name = TextBox2.Text
        email_id = TextBox3.Text
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox2.Text = ""
        TextBox3.Text = ""
        Try
            Dim str1 As String = "insert into BrandstikTesti(Comp_ID, client_name, email_id) values ('" + Comp_ID + "', '" + client_name + "', '" + email_id + "')"
            con.Open()
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(str1, con)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write("This Id already exist")
        End Try
        success.Text = "Client Added Succesfully"
    End Sub

    Private Sub BindListView()
        Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=SuRaj;Initial Catalog=Brandstik2; Integrated Security=True")
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Comp_ID, client_name, email_id FROM BrandstikTesti"
                cmd.Connection = con
                Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    Dim dt As New DataTable()
                    sda.Fill(dt)
                    lvCustomers.DataSource = dt
                    lvCustomers.DataBind()
                End Using
            End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

How can i select emaild id on button click of listview & send mail on that particular mail id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when an asp.net element post back to the server, its being done using asp's premade javascript function `__doPostBack` :

```
<script>
function __doPostBack( eventTarget, eventArgument )
{
    document.Form1.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
    document.Form1.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
    document.Form1.submit();
}
</script>
```

if you want to pass something from the html listview element back to your code behind, you can intercept the button click and submit the `email_id` in the `__EVENTARGUMENT` argument thats being sent back to the server.

for example, you can run a javascript function on asp.net button click, prior to posting back using `onClientClick`:

```
<asp:Button ID="BT_Send" runat="server" Text="Send" OnClick="BT_Send_Click"  OnClientClick="Submit_Stuff" />

function Submit_Stuff(){
    //get your email id here
    var _email_id = "blablabla1"; 

    //manually cause a postback with the email id as argument
    __doPostBack('<%=BT_Send.ClientID%>',_email_id );    

    return false;
}
```

and in your code behind, either on page load or on `BT_Send_Click` function you retrieve the argument:

```
Dim email_id As String = Request.Form("__EVENTARGUMENT")
```

Comment: can you please tell same can be followed if i have checkbox in place of button & one single button at last which can be executed on selected checkbox?

Comment: Yes you could do that, but i dont see the difference. You could stil dopostback the same way for the button, only in code behind check if the checkbox was checked or not...